How to make serialization_alias the default behavior in Pydantic BaseModel
How do i make pydantic serialization_alias as default during model_dump().
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field



class ProjectStage(BaseModel):

    name: dict[str, int] = Field(..., serialization_alias="Username")

    

    class Config:

        pass



a = ProjectStage(name={'foo': 1})


Usual way
output: {'Username': {'foo': 1}}
print(a.model_dump(by_alias=True))

Make by_alias as default in basemodel config
Expected output: {'Username': {'foo': 1}}
print(a.model_dump())


For everyone looking for a solution to this. You can make another class to inherit and override the model_dump() function
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class DefaultDump(BaseModel):
    def model_dump(self, **kwargs) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return super().model_dump(by_alias=True, **kwargs)

class ProjectStage(DefaultDump):
    name: dict[str, int] = Field(..., serialization_alias="Username")

a = ProjectStage(name={'foo': 1})

# Output: {'Username': {'foo': 1}}
print(a.model_dump())

